# Order statistics, no distribution, probability of percentile

Tags: order-statistics

$Let \ Y_1<...<Y_8 \\ be \ the \ order \ statistics \ of \ n \ independent \ observations\ from \ a  \ continuous \ type \ distribution \ with \\ 70th \ percentile \ \pi_0._7 = 27.3$

The question then asks to find: $P(Y_7<27.3)$

I have no clue how to start on the question because in previous questions a distribution was always given but in this one I have nothing to work with. If you don't mind would you just leave me a hint and not answer the whole question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The probability that $Y_7 < 27.3$ is the probability that exactly $7$, or exactly $8$, or exactly $9$, $\ldots$, or exactly $n$ independent samples from the given distribution have value smaller than $27.3$.  The probability that any given sample is smaller than $27.3$ is given to be $0.7$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Sorry I wrote the question wrongly there were only actually 8 terms. I thought about it and if $Y_7$ is smaller than 27.3 then that means that (7/8)*100th percentile should be smaller than 27.3, but then it is stated in the question that the 70th percentile is 27.3 so should the probability of $Y_7$ being smaller than 27.3 0?